# How to call dispatchTouchEvent with a 'delay' in onTouch?

Tags: java, android

I have two views which are siblings of each other. They both cover the full screen. So one is behind the other. If the upper one gets touched (`onTouch`), I delegate the touch events to the one underneath it (with `dispatchTouchEvent`).

But sometimes I want to delay that delegation, till the next time `onTouch` gets called. But somehow that does not work.

An example to clarify:

To `viewA` - which is in front of `viewB` - I have applied the following (simplified) code:

```java
        viewA.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                int touchType = event.getActionMasked();

                if (touchType == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    savedEvent = event;
                    return true; // I also tried returning false here
                } else {
                    if (savedEvent != null) {
                        viewB.dispatchTouchEvent(savedEvent);
                        savedEvent = null;
                    }
                    viewB.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                    return true; // I also tried returning false here
                }
            }
        });
```

To test the `dispatchTouchEvent` call, I have the following code for `viewB`

```java
        viewB.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("test", "test"); // this code gets logged, so it is being called, but the view seems to not execute any of the touch events
                return true;
            }
        });
```

When I change to code for `viewA` to this:

```java
        viewA.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                viewB.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

everything works just fine.

But the thing is that for my use case, I sometimes have to call the `dispatchTouchEvent` method with the `event` parameter outside its originating `onTouch` method, so to speak.

Is this even possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what prevents it from working. If you manually call `dispatchTouchEvent` you should pass through an event that you created yourself with `MotionEvent.obtain()`.

Working example:

```java
        viewA.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                int touchType = event.getActionMasked();

                if (touchType == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // do not do this, somehow passing on a reference of the event directly does not work:
                    // savedEvent = event;

                    // this works though:
                    savedEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);

                    return true;
                } else {
                    if (savedEvent != null) {
                        viewB.dispatchTouchEvent(savedEvent);
                        savedEvent = null;
                    }
                    viewB.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Although I don't understand why that does work and just passing the event reference directly does not, I tested this and it does work perfectly.